# Submit form of Iframe from the parent window

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

```
<iframe id="frame1" name="frame1" align="center" src="committee_assign1.php" height="400" width="700">
                </iframe>


                    <center><input onClick="submitiframeform(); return false;" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                <script type="text/javascript">

function submitiframeform(){
    window.frames['frame1'].document.forms['fypassign'].submit();
}
</script>
```

The above is the main page name committee_assign.php ..

And below is the page where the iframe called committee_assign1.php.

```
<?php
    include '../database.php';
    include 'valid_login.php';
       if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 

    $continue = FALSE;
    $i = 0; 
    while ($continue == FALSE) { 
        if (isset($_POST['id_'.$i])) { 
            $fypcomm = $_POST['fypcomm_'.$i];
            $user = $_POST['id_'.$i];
            $sql = mysql_query(" UPDATE Lecturer SET LectFypCommittee = '$fypcomm' WHERE LectID = '$user' ") 
                or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query($sql);
        } else
            {$continue = TRUE;}
        $i++;
    }

     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>

        window.location.href='../committee/committee_assign1.php'
        </SCRIPT>");

}

    ?>
<head>


</head>

<body>
<form id="fypassign" name="fypassign" method="post" action="" target="_self" onSubmit="">

                <?php


                $counter = 0;

                echo "<table class ='box'>";
                    echo "<thead>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<th align='left' valign='top'>"."Lecturer Name"."</th>";
                    echo "<th align='left' valign='top'>"."FYP Committee"."</th>";    
                    echo "</tr>";

                    $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM Lecturer ORDER BY LectFypCommittee DESC, LectName ASC ") or die(mysql_error());
                    while($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
                        $idcount = "id_".$counter;
                        echo "<input type='hidden' name='$idcount' id='$idcount' value={$info['LectID']}  />";

                        echo "<tr>";

                        echo "<td>";
                            echo $info['LectName'];
                        echo "</td>";

                        echo "<td>";
                            $formname = "fypcomm_".$counter;
                            echo "<select name='$formname'>";
                            //to convert the flag value to user understandable language
                            if ($info['LectFypCommittee'] == '0'){
                                $dbfyp = 'No';
                            }
                            else $dbfyp = 'Yes';

                            echo "<option selected='selected' value='{$info['LectFypCommittee']}'>".$dbfyp."</option>";
                            if ($info['LectFypCommittee'] == '0'){
                                echo "<option value='1'>".'Yes'."</option>";
                            }
                            else echo "<option value='0'>".'No'."</option>";
                            echo "</select>";
                        echo "</td>";

                        echo"</tr>";
                        $counter++;
                    }

                    echo "</table>";
                ?>

                </form>

                </body>
```

I clicked submit button at the parent page and the page refresh but the value is not update.

Can anyone here guide me on this please?

So sorry to post such long codes as I hope you guys could understand more what I am doing. TQ

Answer (score 0):

You have no `input` in your committee_assign.php named submit:

`if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

You must check with something like this:

`if(isset($_POST))`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed to if(isset($_POST)) but the iframe is showing blank and it seems to be executing something as my mouse cursor keeep blinking.. do u know wad happen?

Comment: I dont know what you are trying to do but the problem should be here: while ($continue == FALSE) { 
        if (isset($_POST['id_'.$i])) { 
            $fypcomm = $_POST['fypcomm_'.$i];
            $user = $_POST['id_'.$i];
            $sql = mysql_query(" UPDATE Lecturer SET LectFypCommittee = '$fypcomm' WHERE LectID = '$user' ") 
                or die(mysql_error());
            mysql_query($sql);
        } else
            {$continue = TRUE;}
        $i++;
    }
     echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
        window.location.href='../committee/committee_assign1.php'
        </SCRIPT>");

Comment: Hi, that is the part where I enter the value i have in the form located below to database. Its working before I put into Iframe. Any way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if submit has been posted but you dont have an input named submit. Add an input named submit with some value and check if that post submit exists. You can make it hidden if you dont want to see an extra input.

if($_POST['submit']) is checking if there is a value with key 'submit' in the post array. All the key and value in $_POST array is name and value of a form element respectively.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand. Do you mind explain to me more? Im a newbie in PHP.

Comment: in a normal html form, there is a submit button with the name submit. That is what your code (if(isset($_POST[submit])) is checking. All the values in $_POST are values from the form inputs. The key is the form input names. So if you had an input with a name operation and value submitform, $_POST['operation'] would have the value submitform if the form was submitted.

Comment: Oh.. I understand what you are saying.. There are something with all the values $_POST.. Do you have an example of fixing this? Should replace the upper part of the code with something, but what is it? Kindly enlighten me please. TQ

Comment: You and add a hidden input in the form with a name and value of your choosing. Then replace if($_POST['submit']) with if($_POST['hidden input name'] == "hidden input value"). This ensures that you are doing the processing on the correct form data.